# AWS CLI: How to use variable to filter EFS

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-sagemaker

I want to use the value of the `DOMAIN_ID` variable to filter the EFS to get a FileSystemId. I used the commands below. The first command works and it stores the domain ID. The second one returns an empty list, even though the `DOMAIN_ID` variable is present.

```
DOMAIN_ID=$(aws sagemaker list-domains --query 'Domains[0].DomainId')
aws efs describe-file-systems --query 'FileSystems[?CreationToken==`$DOMAIN_ID`].FileSystemId'
```

Output:

```
[]
```

Expected output:

```
<Some EFS identifier>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works (escaping backticks) -

```
aws efs describe-file-systems --query "FileSystems[?CreationToken==\`$DOMAIN_ID\`].FileSystemId"
```

You can also use describe-domain command instead -

```
$ DOMAIN_ID=$(aws sagemaker list-domains --query 'Domains[0].DomainId' | tr -d '"')
$ aws sagemaker describe-domain --domain-id $DOMAIN_ID --query 'HomeEfsFileSystemId'
```